# How to configure an MVC6 app to work on IIS?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core

So I'm building an MVC6 app in Visual Studio 2015 and have managed to figure most stuff out, however, I haven't yet worked out deployment.

In MVC4 (what I was using before), our process* was publish to a folder, then setup the website in IIS (Right-Click on `Sites` -> `Add Website`).

- Actually, our process is set it up in IIS and TeamCity, but not for test apps like this :).

I followed this process and obviously it's trivial to setup the IIS website and publish to the correct folder...but that does not actually work for me.

We're running IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012 and we've installed the .Net 4.6 runtime on the server.

Comment: Could you describe more about why you think it's not working?

Comment: @Cory - I get an error page telling me I don't have permission to view the folder.

Comment: Can you show us the folder structure?

Comment: If what? On the server box the site was published to `c:\inetpub\websites\sitename`. The published site has a src and wwwroot folder and 3 `.cmd` files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following steps have worked for me and should help you host your project on IIS.

Using Visual Studio 2015 Preview as your IDE,

1. Create an ASP .NET 5 Starter App.
2. Check that it is working outside of IIS.
3. Once complete, publish the application. In this example, I have selected the location `C:\PublishWebApp`.

   3.1. When publishing your application, make sure that you have:

   - Disabled precompilation
   - Selected amd64

     *(See image below)*

[image: Publish Settings Screenshot]

4. Upon a successful publish, go to `C:\PublishWebApp`.You should see the folders `approot` and `wwwroot` inside.
5. Now open the IIS Manager (I am assuming you have the ASP .NET 4.5 feature enabled)
6. Create a new website.

   6.1 : Select the `wwwrooot` folder as the website's physical path. In this example, it is `C:\PublishWebApp\wwwroot`.
7. Check the website to see that it is working. If you encounter any errors, please post them here.

If the precompile option is ticked in the Publish Web Settings window pictured above, then you must

1. Go to the `wwwroot` folder of your published web application. In this example, it is `C:\PublishWebApp\wwwroot`.
2. Locate `web.config`.
3. Inside the folder of your published application, there is an `packages` folder inside of the `approot` folder which should contain a folder named after your application, with a folder for the version underneath. Inside that folder should be a folder named `root`. In `web.config`, set the value for the key `kre-app-base` to the `root` folder. For reference, see the line of code below. In this example, the application name is WebApplication10.

   ```
   <add key="kre-app-base" value="..\approot\packages\WebApplication10\1.0.0\root" />
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out on Monday - I think I have Precompile during publishing ticked, so hopefully that's the issue :).

Comment: If Precompile option is ticked then also it will going to work. But for that you have to do small setting. I will update my answer.

Comment: To get this to work, I unticked Precompiled App Config and importantly, pointed IIS to the `wwwroot` folder. My actual problem was I had IIS pointing to the same folder I was publishing to - which is not correct :). Massive n00b move. P.S. Thanks @dotnetstep!

Comment: @Vartan Simonian: Do you know how to publish asp.net 5 site into IIS using Web Deploy tool?

Comment: @WillHuang I've not done it, but this might help: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

Comment: It's unclear where to add the key kre-app-base in the web.config exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I Spent hours on debugging the issue finally got it worked, steps:

1) Publish your MVC6 application using visual studio into file system,  make sure you are selecting correct DNX Target version in my case its dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1.

In the output folder map "wwwroot" folder to your applicaiton in IIS (DO NOT Map it to sup-applicaiton, only ROOT application in IIS works with DNX for example "Default Web Site").

Answer (score 0):

I have just spent a day trying to get this working. i found this [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/364) (search for posts by GuardRex) invaluable, complete the steps the accepted answer gave, that's the start of it.

Pretty much if you try to add an application to a site there is bunch of workarounds and extra configuration needed that is detailed in the link.

For starters:

1)Make sure you have the HttpPlatform handler installed [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler)

2)Seems obvious but make sure .net5 is installed on your server [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html)

I know this is if you are adding an application to a site, but there's some pitfalls and much needed refinements needed for the deployment process at the moment that everyone should be aware of.