# Problems publishing asp vnext website on IIS 8

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I've followed all instructions from this topic and it still doesn't work . 
[How to configure an MVC6 app to work on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853496/how-to-configure-an-mvc6-app-to-work-on-iis)

If i enable Directory Browsing in IIS, I can see all files from wwwroot . If i disable it , I get this error :

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

Comment: Is your default page set?

Comment: What default page ? I don't have pages in ASP MVC .  Here are my default document settings in IIS : http://s21.postimg.org/vdb7ixinb/Untitled.png

Comment: I hope that you have map wwwroot from your publish directory. Also make sure that your web.config file present in wwwroot.

Comment: Please provide screenshot of your folder structure within IIS.

Comment: Yes, I mapped wwwroot folder . Here's a screenshot with folder structure and IIS settings . http://s23.postimg.org/r3b425q0r/Untitled.png

Comment: Going by the error, looks like you are trying to access the `wwwroot` folder via the Url...is it?...if so, that is not the the way to do it...if you have a file like  `banner.jpeg` under the `wwwroot\images` folder, you still should access it like `http://test.com/<vdir-name>/images/banner.jpeg` and not mention the `wwwroot` folder..

Comment: Did you have "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS" in project.son?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you find anything ? I tried with the ASP Starter Project from VS2015 and it worked ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP 4.5 wasn't installed , even though i had ASP.NET options in IIS Control panel .

In order to install it you have to go to 
Add Roles and Features 
Web Server IIS / Web Server / Application Development and check ASP .NET 4.5 and .NET Extensibility 4.5 (i'm not sure if the last one is required)

The installation took a long time (more than one hour) and the server was freezing from time to time . After that everything worked fine .