# ASP.NET RC1 web app in IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core, iis-8.5

I have setup as per http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html IIS to allow ASP.NET 5 apps to run

I also installed ASP.NET 5 on the machine
The HTTP Platform Handler are also installed (x64)

I created an app pool with the settings like said on the docs and set the pool to no managed code

Set the site to run the app pool i created above.

The system.webServer/handlers section in web.config is unlocked

Once I access the site, the sites loads forever and nothing appears.

In the logs, I get:

> Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel'. Available commands: web.

I can start the application if I run the web.cmd in the approot directly.
It will start the Kestrel server and process properly.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Trying to search for the above error gets me no results.

Server is running IIS 8.5 - windows server 2012 R2 with all the updates done.

EDIT:
I am using ASP.NET 5 RC1
I am not using a virtual directory
I am not publishing to AZURE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MVC 6 Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS 8.5 - Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343861/mvc-6-windows-server-2012-r2-iis-8-5-error-unable-to-load-application-or-exec)

The solution as posted here but also [Problems publishing asp vnext website on IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917865/problems-publishing-asp-vnext-website-on-iis-8)

ASP 4.5 wasn't installed, to install it go to Server Manager , Add Roles and Features, Web Server IIS / Web Server / Application Development and check ASP .NET 4.5 and .NET Extensibility 4.5

Answer (score 0):

The web.config in the wwwroot folder should help IIS figure out what you want to run. Maybe post that?