# Publish and Run an ASP.NET Core 1.0 Application in Production

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

On an ASPNETCORE 1.0 application I have the following on Startup:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment) {

  ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

  builder
    .SetBasePath(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("settings.json", false, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"settings.{hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", false, true);
  builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();

  Configuration = builder.Build();

}
```

I have 2 settings files on my project:

```
settings.json
settings.production.json
```

I published the project using the command line:

```
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=production
dotnet publish --configuration Release
```

The published files include `settings.json` but not `settings.production.json`. And `settings.json` does include the properties which are only in `settings.production.json`. Shouldn't they be merged on publish?

In top of this how to make sure that the application runs on production mode when I copy the files to my server?

Do I need to do anything on `Web.config`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your `project.json` to add your `settings.production.json` file to the `include` section of `publishOptions`:

```
{
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "settings.json",
      "settings.production.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, and when I have the application on the server how to "tell it" to run in production?

Comment: You should set the environment variable  `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=production` on the server on which will be running your app in production. See https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html for more details

Comment: That post talks about Environment Variables but not so much about setting them in the server and the various options. I then found the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049152/asp-net-5-publish-to-iis-setting-aspnet-env-variables