# Development Mode Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, database-connection, asp.net-core-2.0

When I publish a website with .Net MVC Core 2.0 to run in IIS, it results in error (see below picture) when I try ti register an account,
How to I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core deployment to IIS error: Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737585/asp-net-core-deployment-to-iis-error-development-environment-should-not-be-enab)

Answer (score -2):

The error you are getting doesn't look like the errors I have had when trying to publish an Asp Core 2.0 site. Have you tried running the site in the powershell using:

```
dotnet app.dll
```

The fastest way I find doing this is to go to the directory the dll is stored using file explorer then typing "powershell" in the address bar.

Also do you have all the needed modules and tool kits installed? Here is the microsoft article on the needed items
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis