# After web deploy from visual studio, do I need to run dotnet ef update database to perform migration?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

Sorry if the question is a bit long. I couldn't figure out how to phrase it any other way.

I recently deployed an application to google cloud via VS 2017 web deploy. And in the settings tabs there is a section where I can specify the database connection string to apply database migration.

Please let me know if I am wrong here but I though this is the destination database where the migration is applied to.

So I have set the same connection string as the database connection string for runtime and clicked on deploy.

Everything seems to be deployed without any error messages. But when I launch the application it came up with error message described in this link:

[asp-net-core-deployment-to-iis-error-development-environment-should-not-be-enab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737585/asp-net-core-deployment-to-iis-error-development-environment-should-not-be-enab)

So I followed the instructions and when I browse the page, I get an error message saying that

> Applying existing migrations for ApplicationDbContext may resolve this
>   issue

And I see that 'Apply Migrations ' blue button.

My question is , do I have to run the migrations in the command line after this web deployment normally? Or did something go wrong with preparation of the deployment, configuration or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, do I have to run the migrations in the command line after this web deployment normally?

I think this is normal.

This page describes automatic migrations:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554735(v=vs.113).aspx

If I understand it correctly, it's actually Visual Studio that does the migration, so a deployed application will never be able to do the migration itself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I installed SDK on the server and ran dotnet ef update command but doesn't seem to work as expected, so I temporarily gave apppoolidentity permission to run the migration automatically.