# .NET Core 3.0: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT has value Development on publish

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, webdeploy, asp.net-core-3.0

I tried to migrate my ASP.NET Core 2.2 project to the newly released ASP.NET Core 3.0 over the weekend.

Everything looked good in the local environment, but after publishing and deploying to IIS, I faced a few issues as it was using the **development environment configurations**.

I am using **Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition** version **16.3.0**

Upon inspection, I found that the `web.config` file had the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value set to `Development`, which was causing the issue. It was generated with the web publish even in *Release* configuration.

I thought it was supposed to be `Production`? Or did I miss some configuration? I‘ve never faced this issue with any earlier versions of .NET Core.

Now the issue is that if I publish the whole folder again, the issue is likely to come back.

Any solutions or suggestion regarding the root cause of the issue? My `Web.config` looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" requestTimeout="23:00:00" hostingModel="InProcess" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44329" />
        <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you checked the project file if it contains any script for adding environment variables to web.config?

Comment: I have the same problem. What worked in 2.2 doesn't work in 3.1, because `<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />` is set in web.config. Did you found solution?

Comment: Solved issue by using environment variable in `.pubxml` file, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64368721/1662459

Answer (score 0):

Check your csproj file and remove below code if it exists.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Also check the `Properties/PublishProfiles/{profilename.pubxml}`.This will set the Environment name in web.config when the project is published.

Refer to [How to set aspnetcore_environment in publish file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238850/how-to-set-aspnetcore-environment-in-publish-file)

Comment: Checked, not present at these locations. I tried to comment out that line for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT but that line is getting added automatically again on publish

Comment: @Satyajit See my answer. It might be the reason.