# Azure App Service - What modified my web.config?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET Core website running from Kestrel. It is deployed to Azure App Service in production and another as staging.

I like to configure staging as "production-like" so I set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENTNAME = Production` in the Configuration blade of the App Service in the Azure portal. I could see from logs that the code was seeing the environment name as `staging` still.

It turns out `<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENTNAME" value="staging" />` is set in the `web.config` that's on the Azure instance!!

Now, I don't have this set in the `web.config` or any transforms in my codebase, and I don't use the `web.config`, in fact I want nothing to do with it or IIS.

My site is deployed via Azure Pipelines. I use `environmentName` as a build time variable but the YAML only uses it once, to concatenate some text to make up the resource group name.

I then ran `dotnet deploy` using the same command line as Azure Pipelines runs, but the `web.config` it writes into the final publish output folder doesn't contain the offending line either.

It was only a few weeks ago I rebuilt and redeployed all my Azure resources. It was all clean, and it's all scripted.

**Where on Earth has it come from??!**

I'm worried that if I remove it, one day, it'll magically just reappear. It smells very much like someone at Microsoft thought this automagic was a good idea.

Mind you, I've tried to remove it using the App Service Editor and Kudu but I'm not allowed!!

> Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes, please update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting.

So if I'm not setting it, and I'm not allowed to change it, what do I do??

**Update 1**

I've downloaded the artifacts from Pipelines and the web.config *has* the setting in place.

The command run, according to the Pipelines log, was this.

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release --output D:\a\1\s/dotnet-publish-output
```

But when I run that myself, on my machine, it does not meddle with my web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. So whilst on the school run, it occurred to me that the value that the `dotnet` command writes into the `web.config` is correct. How does it know?

The only way it can know is from that environment variable I'm setting in Azure Pipelines and using in my YAML file `azureResourceGroup: tz-$(environmentName)`.

And when I run it on my dev machine vs. running on the Azure build server, that environment variable is not set.

So I set `environmentName` in the environment on my dev machine before running `dotnet publish` and, hey presto! It screws up my `web.config` by adding an environment variable! Amazing.

```
> $env:environmentName = "undocumented-feature"
> dotnet publish --configuration Release --output C:\DATA\Published
...
> cat C:\DATA\Published\web.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyWebsiteYeah.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="undocumented-feature" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxUrl="32768" maxQueryString="262144"/>
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 3E05D228-D9AF-4782-8E33-1F0E69992750-->
```

Isn't that dreadful.

So I solved the whole problem with my websites ignoring the variables set in the portal by changing the variable name in Pipelines to `hostEnvironmentName`.