# Error occurring while trying to access an particulate page in Azure web app

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, exception, azure-web-app-service

I'm a newbie learner of ASP.NET. I was following along [this ASP.NET Razor pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) tutorial and deployed my app to Azure.

But when I'm trying to access [this Movies](https://mahmudx.azurewebsites.net/Movies) page, I'm getting this error.

> **Error.**
>
> An error occurred while processing your request.
>
> Request ID: | f9ecac03-478613f8cb88adc0.
>
> Development Mode Swapping to the Development environment displays
>   detailed information about the error that occurred.
>
> The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed
>   applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from
>   exceptions to end-users. For local debugging, enable the Development
>   environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable
>   to Development and restarting the app.

I've tried [this existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737585/asp-net-core-deployment-to-iis-error-development-environment-should-not-be-enab) and changed the mode to production but the problem remained the same.

**Here is my launch setting -**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50335",
      "sslPort": 44327
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    },
    "Polling_System": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My deployment mode was **Framework-Dependent** and later I changed it to **Self-Contained**.

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem? Thanks.

**P.S.** The page works properly on my machine if the value of `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT":` is set to `"Development"`

Comment: go to your azure app settings and check the value for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT. It cannot be dev

Comment: Can you help me to find that setting page? There are too many options and I'm not well familiar.

Comment: just go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-app-settings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39737834/2791540)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

This is the stanard webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\OurWebApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
     <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
  </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Solution:**

Add or change the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT setting of your web.config.

As the error says,

> The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed
>   applications.

So please change it to other env. I am sorry. Answered wrong just now.

Have look of this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#environments

**Add these code in Web.config or change the value in webconfig.(under site/wwwroot on Kudu):**

```
<environmentVariables>
     <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="[Other env instead of Development]" />
</environmentVariables>
```

Your Kudu page should be: `https://[yourwebsitename].scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`

(Change the [yourwebsitename] to your website name and then you will go to kudu)

**Don't forget to save the edit. This should work without restart.**

Comment: Hi! I put the code int the web.config file. Unfortunately, it didn't work. Here is my web.config code - https://gist.github.com/MahmudX/b4e858b983051fbae520a1886e2efb99

Comment: @MahmudulHasan HI, MahmudulHasan . Why your file is 
 `MahmudXwebConfiq.xml` instead of `Web.config`?

Comment: I just named my gist.

Comment: @MahmudulHasan  put the env between system.webServer. Have a look of my update answer.

Comment: Well, your answer fulfills my requirements. Now I can see the thrown exception. It's because of my app can't connect with the SQL server. I have no idea how to fix this problem. :(

Comment: @MahmudulHasan You can create a new question and post the information about the question. You are welcome!

Comment: @MahmudulHasan And remember to add enough tags of the question. That will let others who know how to solve your problem see your question.