# problem when publishing asp.net core project on a server

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm implementing asp.net core project. I published my project into a package and set it on a main server, but, the database was set on another server. To do that, in the part of connection string of appsetting file, I just changed the server name and database name and when running the project I confront with the following error:
[image]

I appreciate if anyone can suggest me a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that an exception has occurred in your project, but since it is not a development environment, it is impossible to show you the real error message.

If you want to get the real error information, you can try to change the value of the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable from Production or other to `Development` in web.config file, and then refresh to see the real error information.

```
<environmentVariables>
     <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
</environmentVariables>
```

For more details, please refer to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737585/asp-net-core-deployment-to-iis-error-development-environment-should-not-be-enab).