# An error occurred while processing your request. I get this error when trying to log in to my application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, request, asp.net-core-3.1, development-environment

I have published my application when I go to the site and after logging in I get an error message (An error occurred while processing your request.) With below that

(Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.)

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737585/asp-net-core-deployment-to-iis-error-development-environment-should-not-be-enab

Comment: I tried but it still didtn work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use logging and write the error to a file... With more details. Because this error is so global it may be related to many things, with logging it will be clear