# Web application can't communicate with API (stuck in development mode?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core

I've scanned SO and read through many similar posts, but I still can't find one to help.
I have two projects:

1. eContactWeb - a .NET Core 6.0 MVC Web application
2. eContactWebAPI - a .NET Core 6.0 Web API

I added the project reference of the API into the main website.

When I test out my API in swagger, everything works fine.
When I upload the files to the server and launch, I'm getting this error when querying the API:

> The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.

I've already adjusted my Web.config file to look like this
**(note that I've tried value="Production" and value="Development" and still have the same error)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\eContactWeb.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
             <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Here is my launchSettings.json for the Web API:
**(Note: I've changed the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to both "Development" and "Production" and still the same error)**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:15717",
      "sslPort": 44382
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "eContactWebAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7170;http://localhost:5173",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: After you change to `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"`, Have you clean and rebuild your project  then republish again? Hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737585/asp-net-core-deployment-to-iis-error-development-environment-should-not-be-enab) can give you some help.