# ASP.NET MVC app: "An error occurred while processing your request"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

I deployed an ASP.NET MVC web application to AWS.

The application requires me to log in and immediately I try to log in I get this error:

[image: Error]

I don't understand how to change this to **developer mode**.

Also I am confused about how my launch settings and appsettings should look like.

I have tried looking through google and stack overflow for solutions.

I just typed development in the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` within the launch setting.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core deployment to IIS error: Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737585/asp-net-core-deployment-to-iis-error-development-environment-should-not-be-enab)