# Dotnet core ignores ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable

Tags: .net-core, environment-variables, app-config, environment, production-environment

I created a simple webapi project with dotnet core.

I'm trying to set the running environment using the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT system variable.

```
C:\devel\apps\webapi>set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

C:\devel\apps\webapi>echo %ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT%
Production

C:\devel\apps\webapi>dotnet run
Using launch settings from C:\devel\apps\webapi\Properties\launchSettings.json...
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\SSCARANO\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\devel\apps\webapi
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

I tried opening a different console, and also setting it logged in as administrator, but the app is always running on Development mode.

I saw this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40102470/47633) related question, but I'm not using IIS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect that the issue you're encountering is that the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable is defined in the `C:\devel\apps\webapi\Properties\launchSettings.json` file.

The way `dotnet run` works is it loads this file and finds the first profile which `commandName` is `project`, and uses it to run the application. There's a high chance, if you haven't made any changes to that file, that the `environmentVariables` section of that profile contains the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable set to `Development`.

You have 2 options if you want to run the app in `Production` mode:

- change the existing profile and set the variable to `Production`, meaning every time you execute `dotnet run`, it's going to run the app in production mode; or
- add a new profile where the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable is set to `Production`. You can then use it if you execute `dotnet run --launch-profile <name-of-your-new-profile>`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how you have set the environment variable. On the command line you don't need the quotes, so you should instead have this:

```
C:\> set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

C:\> echo %ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT%
Production
```

Comment: I copy pasted your answer but it stills runs on Development mode