# Entity Framework Core Connection String - Environment Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .net core app using entity framework core. When running entity framework migrations or updates via the command line, I get a "value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString"

The connection string is kept as an environment variable:

```
ConnectionStrings__SomeContextConnection  ...(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB...
```

However, when I move that exact same connection string into a .json config file:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {  
    "SomeContextConnection": "...(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB..." 
}
```

Then the entity framework tools recognize the connection string without issue.
When debugging the code, in Startup.cs:

```
var connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("SomeContextConnection");
```

the connectionString variable is set to the correct string when the string is stored in *either* of the two locations, but it crashes when trying to connect to the database when using the environment var.

(note: in the environment variable case, the connection string is escaped so goes from

```
(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB...
```

to

```
(localdb)\\\\MSSQLLocalDB...
```

but the issue persists even after removing the extra back-slashes)

UPDATE:
When the connection string is moved into a Windows level environment variable, it works fine. Seems to only be an issue when using Visual Studio environment variables.

Comment: try putting one backslash

Comment: That was what I mentioned in the 'note' above, but it did not help.

Comment: I think its to do with the Project.Json , check if you have commented lines in either startup application or DB layer if you have one. you cannot have any commented lines in a JSON file

Comment: I removed all the comments, which might have caused issues later, but this problem was not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you remove the double backslash after `(localdb)` so that there's only one backslash.

So once you've corrected that in the environment variable it should look something like this:

`Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB...`

Comment: @MonteChristo Yarrgh is trying to help you out, I suggest you be more gentle in your responses next time someone does that

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a [DesignTimeContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation#from-a-design-time-factory) class for the migrations:

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    AmpContext IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext>.CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigHelper.GetConnectionString();

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new AmpContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

the GetConnectionstring for me is like this and I use it throughout my application (that is for my Web API project and for integration tests):

```
public class ConfigHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the connectionstring from the appsettings.databasestring.json file in the solution root if there is no environment variable to be found
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="solutionBasePath">Optional to not auto resolve the solution base path</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetConnectionString(string solutionBasePath = null)
    {
       //how to set it on IIS on the server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36836533/1343595
        var environmentString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CUSTOMCONNSTR_MyContextDb");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(environmentString))
            return environmentString;

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(solutionBasePath))
            return GetStringFromConfig(Path.Combine(solutionBasePath, "appsettings.databasestring.json"));

        var filePath = Path.Combine(GetSolutionBasePath(), "appsettings.databasestring.json");

        return GetStringFromConfig(filePath);
    }

    private static string GetStringFromConfig(string filePath)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(filePath) //you can change the value of the connectionstring in the appsettings file and add it to gitignore so the change will not effect others
            .Build();

        var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("MyContextDb");
        return connectionString;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current soution base path
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetSolutionBasePath()
    {
        var appPath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
        var binPosition = appPath.IndexOf("\\bin", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        var basePath = appPath.Remove(binPosition);

        var backslashPosition = basePath.LastIndexOf("\\", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        basePath = basePath.Remove(backslashPosition);
        return basePath;
    }
}
```