# Deploying Stage/Production appsettings Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

No the guide seems quite clear (to me at least) on how production settings can be put in place. They just talk about how some of this works, but there is no step-by-step guide. I have done the following:

> Attempting to change the Environment Variable in Project using this [Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments)

I get this error despite the Microsoft Doc explicitly stating to reuse `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`. I cannot save these settings

[image: Shows an ! next to ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT]

Ignoring this issue, it looks like you can manually create these entries in `launchSettings.json` so I have:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:18549/",
      "sslPort": 44319
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/v10Staff",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT_T": "Test"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express (Stage)": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/v10Staff",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Stage"
      }
    },
    "ApplicationName": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:60000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT_T": "Test"
      }
    }
  }
```

> Adding Environment Variable to Server

I have added the environment variable according to the documentation I went to `Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings.` And added the `New User Variable. "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" with value "Stage"

> Configuration Piece using this [Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration)

The next issue I have is, no one shows a working "transform" of the `appsettings.Stage.json`. Does it just completely use the Stage file over the appsettings file? Do I need to just explicitly state what is different? That being said here are my files.

> appsettings.Stage.json

```
{
  "WebServiceAccount": {
    "AccountName": "WebUser",
    "AccountPass": "Wedontcarethatthisishere"
  },
  "ServerLocation": {
    "ServerName": "http://appss.domain.com:8080",
    "DBConnection": "server=svAppNameSTG;Max Pool  Size=6000;database=ES;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  }
}
```

> appsettings.json

```
{
  "WebServiceAccount": {
    "AccountName": "WebUser",
    "AccountPass": "testpass1"
  },
  "ServerLocation": {
    "ServerName": "http://appst.domain.com:8080",
    "DBConnection": "server=svAppNameTST;Max Pool  Size=6000;database=ES;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  }
}
```

I know that the settings, and configuration piece are set up correctly. Because our Test environment works. When I deploy this to our Stage server, I have confirmed that it still points to the Test box.

If anyone has a guide or can spot what is wrong with this that would be great.

> For Posterity

here is the Startup builder

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, you seem to be trying to use the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable multiple times in your first screenshot. You shouldn't be adding new variables, but rather changing the *value* of the variable to reflect the environment you want to use. So to test Stage locally, simple modify the **value** of the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable from `Development` to `Stage`.

I haven't come across using an `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT_T` variable for anything. If this is something you added yourself I suspect it stems from misunderstanding the above and there is probably a better way to achieve what you want. It must be stressed that everything in the `launchSettings.json` is for your local machine/development environment.

---

Setting the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable on your Stage or Production servers will differ depending on how you're hosting. IIS? Azure? AWS? Docker? The following answer discusses setting environment variables for IIS:

[Publish to IIS, setting Environment Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049152/publish-to-iis-setting-environment-variable)

---

Regarding the `appsettings.json`, the values are merged. Everything is read from the base file first, and then everything read from the `appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json` will append or overwrite what is in the base file. In the example you gave, the **WebServiceAccount / AccountName** variable could be omitted from the `appsettings.Stage.json` as it is identical to the value in the base.