# How do I transform appsettings.json in a .NET Core MVC project?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've added additional json config files to my project

```
appsettings.DEV.json
appsettings.QA.json
```

and loaded them in the `Startup` function based on the environment:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    ...
```

And I understand how to change the environment: modify the value of the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable in project properties. However, there does not appear to be the ability to specify different environment variables depending on the configuration, the dropdownlist is labeled "N/A" and disabled.

The only option I see is to manually change the environment variable value, to change which appsettings are used. I'm sure there is a way to do it automatically, or else how would you ever use CI? (other than using a script to change the environment variable, there has to be an easier way).

**The goal here is to setup automated builds and continuous integration  for three environments: DEV, QA, and PROD.** **DEV and QA are on the same machine**, so setting the environment variable that specifies the environment manually is not an option.

[image: Project Properties : Debug section]

Comment: add a new profile by the profile dropdown or add one manually in launchsettings.json

Comment: @EricB how do you associate the profile with a build configuration? Or if not a build configuration, how do you specify which profile is used when you build/publish? (My goal here is to set up automatic builds and continuous integration for different environments, therefore manually changing the environment or profile is not an option)

Comment: then it sounds like you can just access the destination machines and set the environment variable manually, but it should be a one-time thing.

Comment: @EricB This occurred to me however we host two different environments on the same machine (DEV and QA), and Production is on it's own machine. Therefore this solution won't work for DEV|QA

Comment: in that case I think the easiest solution for you might be the [CommandLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#commandline-configuration-provider) config provider

Comment: @EricB Ok I'm reading those docs right now. Would you like to post a solution as an answer? if not, if I figure it out I'll post the answer myself for future readers

Comment: I've never used that provider before, you're on your own now :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've found a solution from Tsengs answer but wish to describe it here for clarity.
The solution is found in the answer to another question however the question is quite different (and I've also expanded upon the answer) so I do not believe this question should be marked as a duplicate.

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049152/publish-to-iis-setting-environment-variable/36836533#36836533)

The solution is to setup different environment variable values on each IIS site for the key `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`

The steps to do so are:

1. Go to your application in IIS and choose `Configuration Editor`.
2. Select `Configuration Editor`
3. Choose `system.webServer/aspNetCore` (RC2 and RTM) or `system.webServer/httpPlatform` (RC1) in `Section` combobox
4. Choose `Applicationhost.config ...` in `From` combobox.
5. Click on `enviromentVariables` element and open edit window.
6. Set your environment variables.
7. Close the window and click Apply.
8. Done

Alternatively, you can modify your `applicationHost.config` file (normally located at `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

And add the following entry under the root `<Configuration>` tag, where "my-iis-site" is the name of your IIS site.

```xml
<location path="my-iis-site">
    <system.webServer>
        <aspNetCore>
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="DEV" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Answer (score 25):

### Determine EnvironmentName from Build Type

For anybody that would like to set the EnvironmentName based on the build type, there is the handy `.UseEnvironment(environmentName)` on `WebHostBuilder` (found in Program Main).

As long as the appropriate compilation symbols are set against the build configurations in your project, you can do something like this to determine the EnvironmentName:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string environmentName;
#if DEBUG
    environmentName = "Development";
#elif STAGING
    environmentName = "Staging";
#elif RELEASE
    environmentName = "Production";
#endif

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseEnvironment(environmentName)
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Comment: what is `#if DEBUG`?

Comment: @Toolkit #if is a pre-processor directive: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if. DEBUG is a predefined preprocessor symbol which is set when you check 'Define DEBUG constant' in the project.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using the default code in `Program.cs`, you don't need to do anything beyond creating the two files in the project.

The default code in `Program.cs` looks like this:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
```

[Here's what that's actually doing:](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L169)

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateDefaultBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new WebHostBuilder();

    ...

    builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    });

    ...

    return builder;
}
```

`env.EnvironmentName` is set to the value of the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable, so all you have to do is create the `appsettings.{ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}.json` file and it will automatically get merged.

Additional note: to get the two files to actually merge, use this syntax:

```
var appSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();
```

not:

```
var appSettings = new AppSettings();
Configuration.Bind("AppSettings", appSettings);
return appSettings;
```

The latter will not returned the merged data.

Thanks to Shawn Wildermuth for [this](https://wildermuth.com/2017/07/06/Program-cs-in-ASP-NET-Core-2-0).

Comment: Of course, you need to add the environment variable at the destination machine, but I guess it goes without saying.

Comment: True, but I typically only use this trick on my dev or test machine to get it to use my dev or test settings. I would not want to depend on an environmental variable on a prod machine.

Comment: Would you care to explain why? I'm just curious?

Comment: It just seems to me an environmental variable is just that - a variable, and there are too many ways it might get changed, or failed to get published etc. That seems a little scary to me in a prod environment. But that is just my own personal preference.

Comment: Where are you getting the "AppSettings" class reference from?

Comment: @PrisonerZERO, It's a custom class that you write to match your appsettings.json file.  Check out the example here: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-get-values-from-appsettings-json-in-net-core

Answer (score 2):

The dialog you linked in the picture is only to configure "launchSettings.json". This file is **not used by your application**.

It is only used by Visual Studio to set the environment and open an URL in the browser when you hit F5 and **nothing** else.

When you want to switch environments, you need to setup an environment variable before launching. How to do this, depends on your environment.

#### Windows (Commandline, cmd.exe)

```
setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"
```

#### Windows (Powershell)

```
$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"
```

#### Linux

```
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
```

#### Linux (Set it for a single command)

```
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development" dotnet run
```

#### Update in regards to the comment

Yes it is machine specific (except for Linux, which you can do per command). However, in IIS you can do that too either via different app pools or by following [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36836533/455493) instructions to add it to IIS

Comment: When you say "setup an environment variable before launching", do you mean as a startup script of some sort? And this variable will be machine specific of course, so how would this solve my problem of having two environments hosted on the same physical machine, in two different IIS sites?

Comment: Well, it's called "Environment" for a reason. Yes it is machine specific (except for Linux, which you can do per command). However, in IIS you can do that too iirc, but you need different app pools, but I **believe** it involves assigning a profile to the app pool and set the environment variable in that users profile

Comment: Or check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36836533/455493. Your admin guys should know how to do that anyways, it's their job ;)

Comment: What if we don't have access to the environment variables on the web servers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using azure add ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT with corresponding value to Application Settings in side of webapp, which will then pick up correct appsettings.{value}.json file

Comment: Why would we want to do that?  Then it's no longer a configuration value, but has to be checked in as code.

Answer (score 0):

We are using the following appsettings.json files:

```
appsettings.json
appsettings.Community.json
```

Since we are using `Blazor WebAssembly` we have these files both in the Server project *and* Client wwwroot. In order for the transformation to take place in Azure App Service we have a Application Setting under Configuration that sets `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Community`.

[image]

To get `appsettings.json` in a Class that can be used via dependency injection code looks like this:

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "UiBaseUrl": "https://example.com",
  "JiraIntegrationSettings": {
    "UseJira": false,
    }
}
```

AppSettings.cs:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string UiBaseUrl { get; set; }

    public JiraIntegrationSettings JiraIntegrationSettings { get; set; }
}

public class JiraIntegrationSettings
{
    public bool UseJira { get; set; }
    
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
var settings = new AppSettings();
Configuration.Bind(settings);
services.AddSingleton(settings);
```

Program.cs:

```
var settings = new ClientAppSettings();
builder.Configuration.Bind(settings);
builder.Services.AddSingleton(settings);
```

This can then be injected into any class or Controller like this example:

```
public ProductsController(ExtendedApplicationDbContext extendedApplicationDbContext, AppSettings settings, ILogger<ProductsController> logger)
{
    _extendedApplicationDbContext = extendedApplicationDbContext;
    _settings = settings;
    _logger = logger;
}
```

Blazor front end injection looks like this:

```
@inject ClientAppSettings ClientAppSettings
```