# Can I run two TestServers on one environment, with different configs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am writing a process that brokers data transfer between two identical APIs (FWIW, one is a local API running in a different container, and the other is in the cloud).

I want to write some test code to ensure that the data transfer code does what it should. Up till now, I've been using [`TestServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost.testserver?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=aspnetcore-2.2) for API tests, but now things might get a little complicated when I want to run two servers. A couple of questions arise:

1. How do I get them to use different `appsettings.json` files? Right now, with just one `TestServer`, it's using the `appsettings.json` of the test project. How do you configure a `TestServer` to use a different config file?
2. Once I have two `TestServers` up and running, do they function as completely independent entities? Most particularly, if I have any `static` values, will their values be shared between the two environments, or can they function independently, as they would in real life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This depends a little bit on how you're creating your TestServer.

   1. If you're using `TestServer`'s constructor (which takes a `IWebHostBuilder` as input), you can use the web host builder's `ConfigureAppConfiguration` method to setup whatever configuration sources you want. Appsettings.json is the default config source if you don't change anything, but it should be easy to create two separate `TestServer`s using different `IWebHostBuilder`s, each with their own `ConfigureAppConfiguration` call.
   2. If you're using the [`WebApplicationFactory` approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory), you can create a [custom `WebApplicationFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-webapplicationfactory) and setup configuration sources in that type's `ConfigureWebHost` method.
2. Since they run in the same process/appdomain, the two TestServers will be separate instances but share statics. If that's not desirable, you could consider running on of the servers out-of-process as a 'real' server (instead of a TestServer) or, maybe even better, avoid the use of statics!

Answer (score 0):

We need a lot more information here... How are you registering your appsettings.json? Are you using DI?

a) Transform your config for your environment (server/cloud)
[How do I transform appsettings.json in a .NET Core MVC project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073959/how-do-i-transform-appsettings-json-in-a-net-core-mvc-project)

b) Create a second appsettings and change that in your application config.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Yes, I am using DI.