# Environment Variable Breaking Site once deployed

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-7.5

This is a really really strange one. If I make a change to the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` server variable in IIS, it *sometimes* breaks my application.

Everything works great on my local machine, production, and demo environments. I wanted to add an additional dev environment where I could test stuff, but have it actually be on our servers vs. debugging in visual studio.

I have my `Startup.cs` configured like so.

```
if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
     options.ConnectionString = Configuration["Data:DevConnection:ConnectionString"];
     options.BaseUrl = Configuration["EnvironmentUrl:Dev:Url"];
     options.IsDev = true;
}
else if (Environment.EnvironmentName.ToLower() == "demo")
{
     options.ConnectionString = Configuration["Data:Demo:ConnectionString"];
     options.BaseUrl = Configuration["EnvironmentUrl:Demo:Url"];
}
else if (Environment.EnvironmentName.ToLower() == "deploydev")
{
     options.ConnectionString = Configuration["Data:DeployDevConnection:ConnectionString"];
     options.BaseUrl = Configuration["EnvironmentUrl:DeployDev:Url"];
}
else
{
     options.ConnectionString = Configuration["Data:ProdConnection:ConnectionString"];
     options.BaseUrl = Configuration["EnvironmentUrl:Prod:Url"];
 }
```

My `appsettings.json` is set up accordingly. In this exact configuration, all of the different environments work, **except** `DeployDev` .. (All of the environments, other than my local machine, are IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008R2 that are clones of each other).

The error I get on `DeployDev` is *The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page “~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml”*

Weird right? There are no code / server config changes between any of the environments other than me adding an environment variable on `DeployDev` called DeployDev using the process laid out here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36836533/1729859 (I did the exact same thing for demo, and it works fine).

So continuing down the rabitt hole and many head scratches, I had the thought to try changing the environment variable on my `DeployDev` instance to something else. I changed it to `Staging` and updated my code to look for `else if (Environment.EnvironmentName.ToLower() == "Staging")` , but left everything else the same. To my suprise, everything started working perfectly.

So to recap, I made no code changes / environment changes, only changed the environment variable from `DeployDev` to `Staging` and voila, everything works. WEIRD!! Has anyone seen this before? Should I send this to the .net core team on github?

Comment: `The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page “~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml”` could you share a section and your _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: I can, yes.. but that shouldn't make a difference as the entire application is working perfectly in 3 / 4 environments with zero code changes between them,

Comment: sorry, but right now this looks like off-topic as we cannot reproduce your problem and right now all looks like you have some code that is not executed for `DeployDev ` env. In provided code, the only difference is `options.IsDev = true;` but you say that is works on Production well.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (Environment.EnvironmentName.ToLower() == "DeployDev")
```

this is your problem.
 You use `ToLower()` so you should compare Environment name with `"DeployDev".ToLower()` equavalent:

```
else if (Environment.EnvironmentName.ToLower() == "deploydev")
```

Comment: That is a good catch, however it doesn't appear to solve my problem. I changed the code to do as you suggested, but still get the original error.