# Publishing asp.net core - Change log file location in web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

When publishing an ASP.Net core app, the generated web.config file has the following entry for logging

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments="..." stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
```

I would like to change the value of "stdoutLogFile". Looking at the question [Publish to IIS, setting Environment Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049152/publish-to-iis-setting-environment-variable), I can similarly change the log file settings in IIS. However, the changes are reverted next time I publish. How can I specify the log file location and prevent it from changing back to the default every time I publish?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?  I'm running into the exact same problem!

Comment: @PatrickDench, see my answer. It worked with a .net core 2 app.

Comment: Worked great, thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem but in a servant linux, can helpme

Answer (score 3):

There is a web.config file in the application that is used to configure the ASP.NET Core Module. You can set the `stdoutLogEnabled` and `stdoutLogFile` attributes in that file. Those settings will be used when running the app in IIS and will persist since it's part of the publish process. [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/aspnet-core-module#configuration-via-webconfig)