# Could not able to fetch the Environment variables from .json file to .NetCoreApp

Tags: c#, json

I have created a .NetCore app in visual Studio and I want connection strings to be fetched from .json files, I have created the .json file launchSettings.json and added the configuration variables as shown.

```
 {
    "profiles": {
      "TwinSample": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "moduleEdgeHubConnectionString": "HostName=xxxx.xxx;DeviceId=xxxxx;ModuleId=xxxxxx;SharedAccessKey=xxxxx",
          "moduleEdgeAgentConnectionString": "HostName=xxxx.xxx;DeviceId=xxxx;ModuleId=xxxxx;SharedAccessKey=xxxxx"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

when I execute it the connection strings in the .cs project is Null that is  moduleEdgeHubConnectionString and moduleEdgeAgentConnectionString is not able fetch the values from .json files.

```
private static string moduleEdgeHubConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("moduleEdgeHubConnectionString");
   private static string moduleEdgeAgentConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("moduleEdgeAgentConnectionString");
```

I have also changed the properties like Build Action to Content and copy to output Directory to copy always.

can you please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Hi Pooja. Environment variables are (at least under windows) the values that you see when you type "set" in a command prompt.  To read config from a json file, follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-config-json-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 1):

In .net core, the default way of storing connection strings is in the section *ConnectionStrings* in the `appsettings.json` file.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "moduleEdgeHubConnectionString": "HostName=xxxx.xxx;DeviceId=xxxxx;ModuleId=xxxxxx;SharedAccessKey=xxxxx",
    "moduleEdgeAgentConnectionString": "HostName=xxxx.xxx;DeviceId=xxxx;ModuleId=xxxxx;SharedAccessKey=xxxxx"
  }
```

To get the connectionstrings, use the frameworks `IConfiguration` interface extension method `GetConnectionString()`

```
var connectionstring = configuration.GetConnectionString("moduleEdgeHubConnectionString"):
```

If you need to have different connectionstrings for different environments you can always add new `appsettings.<EnvironmentName>.json` files.
Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50397539) for more details