# Error after successful deployment on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, .net-core

I have followed a tutorial on how to deploy you .net core application in Azure using Visual Studio IDE .

I have deployed my application successfully but the problem that there is an error that I do not understand .

Here is the error:

> An error occurred while processing your request.
>
> Request ID: 0HLM4N476JQOC:00000001
>   Development Mode
>
> Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
>
> Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment

I have looked for a solution. One of them is to change some settings on `web.config`, but I do not have a `web.config` file in my project.

The other is saying to change the variable in jsonFile `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` from development to production.

It can be enabled by setting the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable to `Development`.

I have searched on the internet for a solution.

I have tried this but it doesn't work .

"this would be another question " : how to see my database tables after migrating to azure ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is it a hosted App Service or on a VM?

Comment: @sellotape not on vm

Comment: With Core as an app service you generally leave web.config alone. Go into the Azure Portal and change that setting to Development under the Application Settings section (or there is a new Configuration section duplicating it for now). See whether when set to Development it explains more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for the below error is:

**Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment**

Check the value of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable. You will have to set this environment variable to "Production" (or other environment than Development)

for that as @Sellotape mentioned go to  go into the Azure Portal and change that setting to Development under the Application Settings section.

You can refer this thread for alternative solution:

[Create Environment setting for dot net core web app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42143152/6049604)

To answer your question " how to see my database tables after migrating to azure "

Open Portal.Azure.com and look for your database and see the changes would be the easiest.