# Are "normal" environment variables more secure than IIS environment variables?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, environment-variables

I have an ASP.Net Core website running on IIS. I need to store some passwords that the site needs to access in production. No paid password storing systems are available to me. I chose to store my passwords in environment variables. So on the production machine I have:

- a service account `my_prod_service_account`
- an application pool `MyProdAppPool` that runs under `my_prod_service_account`
- a website `MyDotNetCoreSite` that runs in the `MyProdAppPool`

**Approach 1: Normal Environment Variables**

I login to the production machine as `my_prod_service_account` and set environment variables for this user in Powershell:

```powershell
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Pwd1", "MyPrecioussss1", "User");
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Pwd2", "MyPrecioussss2", "User");
```

After this MyDotNetCoreSite can read these environment variables.

**Approach 2: system.webServer\aspNetCore Environment Variables**

Something similar can be achieved with `%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` (IIS configuration file) on the production machine. It can be edited manually or [through UI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36836533/1040180), but in the end it looks like this:

```xml
<configuration>
    <location path="MyDotNetCoreSite">
        <system.webServer>
            <aspNetCore>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <environmentVariable name="Pwd1" value="MyPrecioussss1" />
                    <environmentVariable name="Pwd2" value="MyPrecioussss2" />
                </environmentVariables>
            </aspNetCore>
        </system.webServer>            
    </location>
</configuration>
```

After `iisreset` MyDotNetCoreSite can read these values as environment variables.

**Question**

I want to change my password storage method from Approach 1 to Approach 2. The former sets environment variables per user, the latter per site (which I think is neater). But I can't find enough documentation to judge whether Approach 2 has the same level of security as Approach 1. Setting a "normal" environment variable stores it in the registry at `HKEY_Users\my_prod_service_account SID\Environment\Pwd1`. Accessing the registry usually requires elevated permissions, and if someone breaks into it, we will have bigger problems than hackers knowing Pwd1. Is applicationHost.config as secure as the registry? Can I confidently store a password in it?

Comment: If you don't know yet, passwords for application pool identities are stored in applicationHost.config, though encrypted, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/using-encryption-to-protect-passwords

Answer (score 0):

I can just give some head-scratch questions/concerns:
I am curious, have you done a `set` in a command line and checked if any unwanted passwords are listed in the output in plaintext?
Also, if you store all passwords in one file like in Approach#2, this makes a nice honeypot. I do not know how well the encryption works, Lex Li mentioned.

Comment: obviously if I login as my_prod_service_account and do a `set`, it will list all passwords in plain text. But this requires either hacking my_prod_service_account or an admin account who can access the registry and see everyone's environment variables.