# Publishing to IIS ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I have an ASP.NET 3.1 project that get published to a windows server. When I run the project locally on my computer, it works fine; however, when I remote desktop into that windows server, I am getting a 500 error in the network tab and the following error:

[image]

I have changed my environment variable to Development in my Launch.json file, but still received the same error

```json
 "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

When I looked in windows Event Viewer, I found this error:
[image]
Can someone help me figure out what is going on with this?

Comment: No one can help much unless they can touch your code base, https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#11-why-do-i-get-a-platformnotsupported-exception-when-my-application-hits-a-sqlclient-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the value of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable. You will have to set this environment variable to "Production"(or other environment than Development).

Otherwise, you can update web.config like this:

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\Application.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
        </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36836533/13336642) for more details.