# How to use different appsettings.json file for different deployment?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, deployment, appsettings

I have .NET Core 7 WEB API project. In there, I have 3 settings files. More pecisely:

- appsettings.json
- appsettings.QA.json
- appsettings.Production.json
- appsettings.Development.json.

The behavior I want to achieve is:

When I run: `dotnet publish -c QA -o deploy` and host the application on IIS, it is using appsettings.QA.json file.

What is happening:

The application always uses appsettings.Production.json as default configuraiton.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: `-c` should be `Release` or `Debug`. It has nothing to do with your environment name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you publish your application using `dotnet publish -c QA -o deploy`, the `-c QA` flag specifies that the build should use the QA configuration, but it doesn't set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable to `QA`.

To achieve this in the iis you can follow below steps:

1. Open the IIS Manager, Select your application/site from the left pane
2. Open the `Configuration Editor`
3. From the Section dropdown, select `system.webServer/aspNetCore`.
4. In the `environmentVariables` collection, add an entry with `name` as `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` and `value` as `QA`.

after making changes the web.config will look like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\App.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="QA" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable with the env you want to use.

```
SET DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=QA
```

For more info:
[Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 2):

The environment name in `appsettings.{EnvironmentName}.json` (like `QA` in `appsettings.QA.json`) comes from corresponding environment variable (`DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` or `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#environments)). You need to set this environment variable in IIS for corresponding site (or globally).

One option is to switch to use [publishing profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#pubxml-files) and specify `EnvironmentName` in it - see [Windows - IIS deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#windows---iis-deployments).

Or just set it manually for the site - see [Publish to IIS, setting Environment Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31049152/2501279)